# How to prove this metric function is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

Suppose that X and Y are metric spaces with distance functions dX and dY and define a function

d : (X × Y ) × (X × Y ) → [0, ∞) by

d((x, y),(x',y')) = dX(x, x') + dY (y, y').

Check that d defines a metric on X × Y . Show that the map
π : X × Y → X given by π(x, y) = x is continuous with respect to the metrics d and dX.

Comment: Do you know definitions?

Comment: This looks like a standard homework exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Take some $(x_0,y_0)\in X\times Y$. Suppose we've been given an $\epsilon > 0$. Our objective is to find a $\delta$ such that, for some point $(x,y)\in X\times Y$,

$$d((x_0,y_0),(x,y))<\delta \implies dX(\pi(x_0,y_0),\pi(x,y)) = dX(x_0,x)<\epsilon.$$

By definition,

$$d((x_0,y_0),(x,y)) = dX((x_0,x)) + dY(y_0,y). $$

If we choose $\delta = \epsilon$, then, if

$$d((x_0,y_0),(x,y))<\delta = \epsilon$$

then

$$dX(x_0,x) \leq dX(x_0,x) + dY(y_0,y) = d((x_0,y_0),(x,y))<\delta = \epsilon.$$